# How to use BertForSequenceClassification for token max_length set at 1700?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to perform author classification on the Reuters 50 50 dataset, where the max token length is 1600+ tokens and there are 50 classes/authors in total.

With `max_length=1700` and `batch_size=1`, I'm getting `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory`. This error can be prevented by setting `max_length=512`, but this has the unwanted effect of truncating the texts.

**Tokenizing and encoding:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
MAX_LEN = 1700
def get_encodings(texts):
    token_ids = []
    attention_masks = []
    for text in texts:
        token_id = tokenizer.encode(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=MAX_LEN)
        token_ids.append(token_id)
    return token_ids

def pad_encodings(encodings):
    return pad_sequences(encodings, maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long", 
                          value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")

def get_attention_masks(padded_encodings):
    attention_masks = []
    for encoding in padded_encodings:
        attention_mask = [int(token_id > 0) for token_id in encoding]
        attention_masks.append(attention_mask)
    return attention_masks


train_encodings = get_encodings(train_df.text.values)
train_encodings = pad_encodings(train_encodings)
train_attention_masks = get_attention_masks(train_encodings)

test_encodings = get_encodings(test_df.text.values)
test_encodings = pad_encodings(test_encodings)
test_attention_masks = get_attention_masks(test_encodings)
```

**Packing into Dataset and Dataloader:**

```
X_train = torch.tensor(train_encodings)
y_train = torch.tensor(train_df.author_id.values)
train_masks = torch.tensor(train_attention_masks)

X_test = torch.tensor(test_encodings)
y_test = torch.tensor(test_df.author_id.values)
test_masks = torch.tensor(test_attention_masks)

batch_size = 1

# Create the DataLoader for our training set.
train_data = TensorDataset(X_train, train_masks, y_train)
train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)

validation_data = TensorDataset(X_test, test_masks, y_test)
validation_sampler = SequentialSampler(validation_data)
validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_data, sampler=validation_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Model setup:**

```
if torch.cuda.is_available():    
    device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(
    'bert-base-uncased',
    num_labels = 50,
    output_attentions = False,
    output_hidden_states = False,
    max_position_embeddings=MAX_LEN
)

model = BertForSequenceClassification(config)

model.to(device)


optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),
                  lr = 2e-5, 
                  eps = 1e-8 
                )
```

**Training:**

```
for epoch_i in range(0, epochs):

    model.train()

    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

        b_texts = batch[0].to(device)
        b_attention_masks = batch[1].to(device)
        b_authors = batch[2].to(device)

        model.zero_grad()        

        outputs = model(b_texts, 
                        token_type_ids=None, 
                        attention_mask=b_attention_masks, 
                        labels=b_authors) <------- ERROR HERE
```

**Error:**

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 6.00 GiB (GPU 0; 7.93 GiB total capacity; 1.96 GiB already allocated; 5.43 GiB free; 536.50 KiB cached)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are training on a TPU, your chances are extremely low of ever having enough GPU RAM with any of the available GPUs right now.
For some BERT models, the model alone takes well above 10GB in RAM, and a doubling in sequence length beyond 512 tokens takes about that much more in memory. For reference, a Titan RTX with 24 GB GPU RAM (most of what is currently available for a single GPU), can barely fit 24 samples of 512 tokens in length at the same time.

Fortunately, most of the networks still yield a very decent performance when truncating the samples, but this is of course task-specific. Also keep in mind that - unless you are training from scratch - all of the pre-trained models are generally trained on 512 token limits. To my knowledge, the only model currently supporting longer sequences is [`Bart`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bart.html), which allows up to 1024 tokens in length.

Comment: This makes sense in light of everything. Thanks

Comment: @doctopus: As addition to the answer of dennliner. huggingface is currently working on a [longformer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3783) implementation which allows a sequenzlength of 4096.

Comment: @cronoik: How did you learn about `longformer`? Was it announced on Twitter?

Comment: Generally, twitter is probably the best source if you want to stay at the cutting edge, unless you're willing to wade through endless amounts of released arXiv papers by yourself ;-)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: I subscribed to arXiv and skim through their mail on a daily base. :)

Comment: @dennlinger: Do you recommend any Twitter feeds to follow? Or are you specifically talking about Huggingface?

Comment: @cronoik: Do you subscribe to the "Computation and Language" (cs.CL) subgroup on arxiv, or to the broader "Artificial Intelligence" or "Machine Learning" groups?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 just cs.CL but pick what you like.

Comment: Please consider moving overly long comment discussions to chat. There, issues like this are better discussed! I created a room [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213143/how-to-use-bertforsequenceclassification-for-token-max-length-set-at-1700)